# Extension that overrides new tab when installed does not detect the index html file

Tags: javascript, html, json

edit: [Chrome Extension URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rayztv-custom-override/ojkhjjbpjenaecnopomnejengjelfolg?hl=es)

- Edit 2: Seems like the update that actually contains `index.html` file did not publish beacouse of google puting it under revision. I dont know how i forgot to put `index.html` file in the upload zip beacouse i only selected the extension folder then zipped it and uploaded. Sorry for not checking after publishing :( *

Answer (score 0):

Your packed CRX doesn't contain an `index.html` file. Try repacking the extension and uploading it again.

Comment: To be clear: I downloaded your extension and looked at the contents. There isn't an `index.html` in the archive.

Comment: Thanks, i checked the .CRX package and yes there is no index.html. The problem is that it seems like the update i launched didnt publish so the extension is stuck in 0.9 version (my update version is 1.0). I discovered the update is under revision.